# Подключение проекта на php symfony к БД postgresql 13

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony

Есть проект на symfony и БД postgres 13, пытаюсь провести миграцию  "symfony console make:migration". В ответ получаю вот это: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я так понял что при настройке где-то упустил что-то. В файле .env прописал "DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:pass0rd@winsrv:5432/Test?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8
в файле doctrine.yaml прописал:

```
    driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
    server_version: '13'
    charset: utf8
    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

Пните пожалуйста в нужное русло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данная проблема заключается в проблеме с логином и паролем. Добавил новый логин и пароль и все заработало. В файле doctrine.yaml можно не прописывать ничего